# Virtual service Port configuration works for one namespace but not for the other

Tags: kubernetes, istio-gateway

I've deployed the same app in k8s in two different namespaces: `nsgreen` and `nsblue`.
The desired outcome is to be able to access apps for both namespaces on port 80:

- nsgreen: http://myapp.int.mydomain.com
- nsblue: http://myapp-blue.int.mydomain.com

My gateway is created in the `istio-system` namespace as follows:

```
### Gateway
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: mygateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
  - hosts:
    - myapp-blue.int.mydomain.com
    port:
      name: myapp-server-blue
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
  - hosts:
    - myapp.int.mydomain.com
    port:
      name: myapp-server
      number: 80
      protocol: HTTP
```

Virtual service for my-app in nsblue:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myapp-vs-blue
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  gateways:
  - mygateway
  hosts:
  - myapp-blue.int.mydomain.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp-server-blue.nsblue.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
      weight: 100
```

Virtual service for my app in nsgreen

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  gateways:
  - mygateway
  hosts:
  - myapp.int.mydomain.com
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: myapp-server.nsgreen.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8080
      weight: 100
```

When accessing http://myapp.int.mydomain.com (nsgreen), port 80 seems to be working fine but in the case of myapp-blue (nsblue), I can only access it through port 8080 (http://myapp-blue.int.mydomain.com:8080) instead of 80.

Note: In case that matters, both namespaces have the label `istio-injection=enabled`.

Can anyone shed some light on what's wrong with my yaml files to achieve the desired outcome above?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor? It is important to reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's v.1.16.1. It's an on-premise cluster that I've inherited. Unfortunately, setup steps were never recorded by the people that created the cluster.

Comment: You are using very old, deprecated version of Kubernetes (and probably istio). Without setup steps we cannot reproduce your problem. Could you install newest version of Kubernetes and Istio and test your configuration?

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for taking the time to respond to my question.
I'll try to see If I can find spare resources to create a fresh cluster with later/latest version.

Comment: did you try to test it?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have the time to test it yet.

Comment: Do you have any updates?